# I Can't Bring Data to DropDownList Selectively (System.NullReferenceException Error)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, drop-down-menu

I have 3 tables in my database as `"tbl_User", "tbl_City", "tbl_Town"`.

In the `"tbl_City"`, I have

```
 - cityno int [PK],
 - cityname nvarchar(50)
```

areas.

In the `"tbl_Town"`, I have

```
 - townno int,
 - townname nvarchar(50),
 - cityno int
```

areas.

In the `"tbl_User"`, I have

```
- userid int [PK],
 - email nvarchar(50),
 - password nvarchar(50),
 - city int,
 - town int
```

areas.

While the user is registering on the site, he must choose city and town. So I can save city and town as number in `"tbl_User"`. What I want to do is: When the user goes to the "profile.aspx" I want the city and the town to be seen in the DropDownList selectively. My "profile.aspx.cs" code is as follows:

```
private void GetCityAndTownSelectively()
{
    if (Session["userid"] != null)
    {
        DataRow dr = function.GetDataRow("SELECT tbl_City.cityno, tbl_City.cityname, tbl_Town.townno, tbl_Town.townname FROM tbl_User LEFT JOIN tbl_City on tbl_City.cityno = tbl_User.city LEFT JOIN tbl_Town on tbl_Town.townno = tbl_User.town WHERE userid=" + Session["userid"].ToString());
        if (dr == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            DrpDwnLstCity.ClearSelection();
            DrpDwnLstCity.Items.FindByValue(dr["cityno"].ToString()).Selected = true;
            DrpDwnLstTown.ClearSelection();
            DrpDwnLstTown.Items.FindByValue(dr["townno"].ToString()).Selected = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
}
```

I changed my code but I am still get an error: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in aytasarim.dll but was not handled in user code.

Comment: You don't have cityno and townno in your select statement. That's why you get cityno column does not exist error.

Comment: You're only selecting 2 columns by `SELECT tbl_City.cityname, tbl_Town.townname FROM ....`. The column name `cityno` certainly doesn't exist.

Comment: So,how do I change the code to work as I want?

Answer (score 0):

Your Sql query is wrong

```
SELECT tbl_City.cityname, tbl_Town.townname FROM tbl_User 
LEFT JOIN tbl_City on tbl_City.cityno = tbl_User.city 
LEFT JOIN tbl_Town on tbl_Town.townno = tbl_User.town 
WHERE userid="";
```

As `cityno` is not present in `tbl_User` table and you are creating `join` on column having value int in 1 table and Nvarchar in other table

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
private void GetCityAndTownSelectively()
{
    if (Session["userid"] != null)
    {
        DataRow dr = function.GetDataRow("SELECT tbl_City.cityno, tbl_City.cityname, tbl_Town.townno, tbl_Town.townname FROM tbl_User LEFT JOIN tbl_City on tbl_City.cityno = tbl_User.city LEFT JOIN tbl_Town on tbl_Town.townno = tbl_User.town WHERE userid=" + Session["userid"].ToString());
        if (dr == null)
        {
            Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            DrpDwnLstCity.ClearSelection();
            DrpDwnLstCity.Items.FindByValue(dr["cityno"].ToString()).Selected = true;
            DrpDwnLstTown.ClearSelection();
            DrpDwnLstTown.Items.FindByValue(dr["townno"].ToString()).Selected = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("default.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've try this but I get an error: An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in aytasarim.dll but was not handled in user code.

Comment: I've try again but unfortunately I am still getting same error. I don't know why. I've try this SQL query (SELECT query) in MS SQL and it is working but in the program it's not working.

Comment: OK, are you sure you have values in the dropdown? If your dropdown is empty and you try to find by value then you would get NullReferenceException

Comment: Yes I have values in my DropDownList. I have 2 methods for call all the cities and towns.

Comment: Okey, I got close to solving the problem. I can bring city selectively now, but I can't bring town selectively. Maybe it's because; town table contact with the city table.